# Why did the plague of the first born work in changing Pharaoh's mind? (in light of explanation of R Albo and Sforno on Pharaoh's free will)

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, repentance-teshuvah, plagues-makkos

We are told that Hashem hardened the heart of Pharaoh in order that he would not be intimidated into letting the Jewish people go, but would still have the free will to be able to decide based on how evil he still was only, i.e. true repentance rather than forced repentance. See e.g. [Sefer Ikkarim 4:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_4.25.7?lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=en) and Sforno on [Shemot 7:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=en) and [9:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.9.35?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=en).

Given this, what is it about the 10th plague that caused Pharaoh to truly repent, rather than repent out of force? Or maybe it wasn't the 10th plague so the question simplifies: what in the end caused Pharaoh to finally repent, truly?

Comment: If you follow the view that he ended up in Ninveh after Kriyas Yam Suf and rebuilt his life there, when Yonah rocked up, informing the town of the need to repent, the memory of Mitzrayim was enough to spur him into action!

Comment: @Dov that means that the memory of Mitzrayim intimidated him!

Comment: or he remembered that Hashem was a greater force and there was inherent need to repent...

Comment: @Dov sounds like a deep discussion

Comment: "Truly repent", was it? I remember from writing my book with chiddushim on Torah that there are some meforshim that say that the "repentance" of pharaoh was merely out of fear and was not a true, out of love repentance. He just wanted the Jewish people to leave, in order for the plagues to stop.

Comment: @Shmuel indeed that would be the exact opposite shita of R Albo and Sforno

Comment: I wrote a whole chapter about it, but due to surgery I have no access to it. Will be IYH uploading it to an answer if that is still needed later on :)

Comment: Maybe Hashem unhardened it because the need for it to be hardened had passed?

Comment: @Shmuel reminder. I hope your surgery went/goes well. Refuah Shelema

Comment: @MosesSupposes that could very well be the answer, but have you got a source?

Comment: @RabbiKaii thanks, oops forgot it. I recovered fully, B"H! I will try to answer it :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii no, sorry - just what makes sense to me

Answer (score 2):

So, in my "to be published" sefer with chiddushim Al HaTorah, I wrote an entire chapter on this episode. I wrote it in Dutch, so am trying to translate it :)

[Rashi on Shemos 7:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.7.3.1?vhe=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> וְגָלוּי לְפָנַי שֶׁאֵין נַחַת רוּחַ בָּאֻמּוֹת לָתֵת לֵב שָׁלֵם
> לָשׁוּב - and it is manifest to Me that the heathen nations find no
> spiritual satisfaction in setting their whole heart to return to Me
> penitently

He goes on to say that "it is better that his (Pharaoh's) heart should be hardened in order that My signs may be multiplied against him so that ye may recognise My divine power. Such, indeed, is the method of the Holy One, blessed be He: He brings punishment upon the nations so that Israel may hear of it and fear Him.".

This seems problematic, since should it be obvious that G-d gives us the ability to truly return to Him? Why did G-d did not give Pharaoh this option?

I then cite the Rambam in [Shemonah Perakim (chapter 8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Eight_Chapters.8.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in which he says that all that happened to B'nei Yisrael in Mitzrayim was done with the free will of pharaoh:

> This they did through the dictates of their own free will and the evil passions of their hearts, without any external constraint forcing them thereto. The punishment which G-d then inflicted upon them was that He withheld from them the power of repentance, so that there should fall upon them that punishment which justice declared should he meted out to them. The fact that they were prevented from repenting manifested itself by Pharaoh's not dismissing them.

The Siftei Chakhamim on Rashi explains:

> It is better for Me that his heart be hardened. . . In other words, if I do not harden Pharaoh’s heart he will surely repent. **But it is revealed to Me that he will not really repent wholeheartedly.** And then, if I smite him with plagues and punish him, people will say that Hashem brings punishment upon repenters — for they will not know that Pharaoh’s repentance was not wholehearted. Therefore I will harden his heart so that he will not repent at all, and then I will be able to increase My wonders and punish him for all to see.

The [Ramban (Shemos 7:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.3?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) asks a famous question:

> If G-d hardened Pharaoh’s heart, what then was his transgression [since he had no choice]?

The Ramban answers:

> There are two answers, which both hold true: First, Pharaoh, in his wickedness, had unjustifiably treated the Jews terribly, so he was punished with the withdrawal of the path of repentance, and there are many verses regarding this in the Torah and the Writings, and he was punished by his original deeds. Secondly, only the second half of the [ten] plagues were brought upon Egypt due to Pharaoh’s transgressions, as the Torah states, And Pharaoh’s heart was strengthened, (Shemot 7:13, 26; 8:15), and Pharaoh hardened his heart (ibid. 8:28, 9:7). He did not want to send the Jews out of Egypt for the glory of God; rather, when the plagues increased and he was becoming too worn out to withstand them, his heart softened and he decided to send them out because of the severity of the plagues themselves, but not in order to do the will of his Creator.

So based on these meforshim, it would seem that Pharaoh, even by the tenth plague, never truly repented, he just wanted to "get it over with".

The Tur, Rabbi Yaakov ben Asher, in his commentary Tur HaAroch on Shemos 9:12 explains that Gd had to harden Pharaoh's heart to prevent Pharaoh from letting the Jewish people go sooner. This, the Tur explains, is to ensure that the full range of plagues were exposed to Mitzrayim.

The Malbim says that G-d hardened the heart of pharaoh because then, the Jewish people wouldn't be let go by him, so that pharaoh and the Egyptians could see G-ds existence and to let them see that G-d rules the world.

Rav Moshe Feinstein (Darash Moshe al HaTorah, parashas Vaera, p. 106)  explains that after the 6 plagues, pharaoh only wanted to let the Jewish people go out of fear for further plagues, not because he acknowledged G-d.

See also [Shemos Rabbah 13:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.13.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: Stunning answer, and filled with wonders I've never heard before, thank you very much. Everything until and including the Rambam seems to hold by the opinion in the OP, not sure about the last 3? If we can figure that any of them do hold by it, then I will accept this answer

Comment: Ever planning on translating the full work? I would like a chance to read it :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii thanks. No, not at the moment. But I covered the whole Torah (parsha) so maybe for future answers, I will use it :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii sorry, but I don't quite understand your last point.  The last three also say that it wasn't full, sincere teshuvah, right?

Comment: They do, but if they don't hold by the point that Hashem hardened Pharaoh's heart _in order to **ensure** his true free will_, then I can't accept them as answer